# Bluetooth tethering from Samsung Galaxy 8 used to worked great

Tags: connection-issues, bluetooth-tethering

I have a Samsung Galaxy 8. I use it a lot to tether my Samsung tablet which hasn't pushed an update in a long time. I found that bluetooth tethering saved my phone battery far better than wifi hotspotting. My data speeds were fine for me with blutooth.

The latest update that Samsung or Cspire pushed to my phone ruined that! Now the tablet will not stay connected to the phone by bluetooth for longer than a minute, only wifi. However bluetooth still works fine with my vehicle connection. I still feel it's a phone issue since it happened right after the update. What can I do? I'm technology challenged! Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: What is Galaxy 8?